# Installing Raid 1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid

I am trying to install raid 1 on my new ubuntu server using software raid.

My drives are 2 x 3TB

I have set the format of the drives to gpt. Created 3 partitions (1mb - grub) (2gb swap) and the rest ext with / mount point.

The issue comes when configuring raid. When i raid the two boot partitions i cant set it to reserved boot mode, only ext 4 with /boot so I am unable to install grub successfully.

I have tried not raiding the grub partitions and installing grub directly on each drive but it fails to boot with disk error muuidd with a hex.

Any help is appreciated. I have followed numerous tutorials but keep running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this in the past, installing Linux onto a software RAID configuration on 2 drives.  What I've found, is that you need to se the /boot partition onto a single drive.  And only once the kernel boots into a basic Linux OS does the software RAID to actually work.  From there, I've had to manually (although scripted) to copy the /boot partition from the primary drive to the secondary drive.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So how would the config be on the drive. RAID swap, raid ext and just 2 single boot partitions no raid. One configured, one not?